# ASP.NET Page.OnLoad executes twice

Tags: asp.net

Anyone have any idea when and why Page.OnLoad() executes twice in the ASP.NET lifecicle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a an IMAGE element with a blank string for the URL on that page?

This one has caught so many people before  :)

Comment: Funny I posted the same Question a while back and yes  <img src=""> was the culprit !

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any tags like <img src="#"> or <img src="">, that makes IIS load the page twice. It's a classic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `AutoEventWireUp` set to `true` and also attaching an event handler in code? This is a common reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that Visual Studio browser link is enabled. To figure out what caused the issue you can inspect the Request object.

[image]

Comment: Heh, I know, just posting here for other people or future me :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any controls with AutoPostBack set to true ? That will cause the Page object to be recreated and therefore the PageLoad method will execute again.