# An inline style causes an extra request

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

On_Load is being called twice in a page.  After using Firebug I found that it requests

`http://localhost/default.aspx`

then it does another request to

`http://localhost/default.aspx#ced3db`

I search for `"#ced3db"` and found it in a `<table>` in the page. When I remove its background attribute, the problem disapears.

```
<table width="430" height="281" border="0" 
    background="#ced3db" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I used a style attribute to avoid requesting the page twice. But, I still need to know: why there are two requests being made? I would like to understand the root cause to avoid re-requesting a page, because it can make any website slower.

**Edit:** The question has nothing to do with inline styles vs. using CSS files. It is about avoiding unintentionally re-requesting the page for performance reasons.

**Note:**  On_Load can be called twice for several reasons, See  [ASP.NET Page.OnLoad executes twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610061/asp-net-page-onload-executes-twice)

- AutoEventWireUp is true and you override On_Load.
- A user control contains AutoEventWireUp with true. Did not try that.
- The page or master page contains `<img src="#"> or <img src="">`

Comment: Can you provide a link to how using a style attribute can slow your page down?  That's not something I've ever heard before.

Comment: I agree... it might make your markup more if you keep declaring inline styles, that's why you'd use CSS classes and stylesheets.  Plus, those attributes are deprecated.

Comment: @DoctorMick you got it wrong, I rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `background` attribute for a `table` element expects a URL of an image.  (I don't think it's even a proper attribute for that element, or at least I've never seen it used.  Might have browser-specific behavior.)

If that's the case, then this *kind of* makes sense.  At the end of the question you note:

> - The page or master page contains `<img src="#">` or `<img src="">`

So that seems to be what's happening here.  The browser is interpreting that color tag as a URL and making a request back to the server resource to try to fetch it, since a hash URL by itself defaults to the current page.  In an anchor tag it would just move the focus to that tag on the page, but in a resource-reference tag (such as an `img`, but in this case an attribute on `table` which expects a URL) it has to make another request.

**Update:** A little Googling on the attribute turns up a number of pages similar to [this one](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_TABLE_BACKGROUND.html), which seem to indicate that it is expecting a URL.

Indeed, the `table` element doesn't seem to *officially* have a `background` attribute.  At least [not in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) or [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

Answer (score -1):

The `background` attribute does not accept hex colors as inputs. You should be using CSS anyway. Use the `background-color` CSS property instead.

See this fiddle for the `background` attribute not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/SrEDB/

And this working with the CSS property.

http://jsfiddle.net/SrEDB/

Comment: The question is about why two requests to the web server are generated, not about inline styles vs. CSS.

Comment: I'll think you'll find that the second request won't be made if the above change is made.